# Service Worker fetch event is not being triggered

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker

```
      self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log('SW Installed');
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open('static')
        .then(function (cache) {
          cache.addAll([
            '/',
            '/static/js/renderjson.js',
            "/static/css/app.css",
            '/static/js/contribute.js',
            "http://pending.biothings.io/denovodb/metadata",
            "http://pending.biothings.io/ccle/metadata",
            "http://pending.biothings.io/kaviar/metadata",
            "http://pending.biothings.io/biomuta/metadata",
            "http://pending.biothings.io/fire/metadata",
          ]);
        })
    );
  });

  self.addEventListener('activate', function () {
    console.log('SW Activated');
  });

  self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('FETCH',event.request);
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response) {
                // retrieve from cache
                console.log('Found ', event.request.url, ' in cache');
                return response;
            }

            // if not found in cache, return default offline content (only if this is a navigation request)
            if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
                return caches.match('/');
            }

            // fetch as normal
            console.log('Network request for ', event.request.url);
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
  });
```

I'm new to PWA's so bear with me, I'm running a tornado server here is the registration:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/js/worker.js');
    console.log('Service Worker registered');
  });
}
```

I put a few console logs to see if the fetch event was being triggered but nothing seems to be happening, when I check the offline box on the Application tab and refresh the app does not work offline. All the assets are cached correctly and verified they are there. Looks like the last bit is just making the Worker server the right cached files.

Comment: So everything works correctly but you do not see the console.log output? That's may happen to be because service-worker has a different frame from your website, as it was designed to work in a separate stream.

Comment: You can debug your service-worker by changing active frame for console by selecting it here: https://d3a1eqpdtt5fg4.cloudfront.net/items/1g3W1S2L1E3o3L1X3l2h/%5B2d91819e9489c11be423a56bfbd23f1d%5D_Image+2019-03-20+at+06.58.20.png?v=3207a5c8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case specifically, our site just needed to use https for the worker to activate properly.  after doing that the listeners worked perfectly. I would recommend using Workbox, a lot easier!